# Is it possible to hide .so files in Android NDK development?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an Android app on Android Studio 3.6.1.

I used NDK for the first time today.
When I unzipped my apk, there was a folder for each platform under the lib folder, with a .so file in each folder.

I have a question.
Is it possible to prevent this .so file from being extracted just by extracting apk?
Indeed, reverse-engineering .so files is difficult. However, I don't like the .so file being diverted to steal the return value.

my CMakeLists.txt is...

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Yes, it is default CMakeLists.txt.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it, how would the device find it to run the functions in it?  Of course you can't.

And really, if you're worried about that you should see how easily reversible Java and Kotlin are.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm afraid I'll have to give up.

Comment: java/kotlin compiles to byte-code. C compiles to native machine code. So there's no chance to get source code from *.so file.

Comment: `Snowman` can decompile *.so but output is more like dirty C than just a source code.